# how to get the value of the array

Tags: php

I have an array ,i wanna get the value of the array of array i think . but i cant get the value of all array values.So please tell me which way i can get all values.

```
print_r($demo);

Array ( [] => Array ( [0] => research , monitoring , benchmarking )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => online marketing software )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => online exposure )
        [3] => Array ( [0] => research , monitoring , benchmarking )
        [4] => Array ( [0] => research , monitoring , benchmarking )
        [5] => Array ( [0] => Internet Marketing platform providing research , monitoring , benchmarking & ; recommendations - )
        [6] => Array ( [0] => research monitoring benchmarking )
        [7] => Array ( [0] => online marketing )
        [8] => Array ( [0] => online exposure )
        [9] => Array ( [0] => Online Marketing )
        [10] => Array ( [0] => online exposure )
        [11] => Array ( [0] => marketing software )
        [12] => Array ( [0] => Internet Marketing platform providing research monitoring benchmarking amp recommendations )
        [13] => Array ( [0] => Learn how )
        [14] => Array ( [0] => rough seas )
        [15] => Array ( [0] => tools empowering you )
        [16] => Array ( [0] => complex take control )
        [17] => Array ( [0] => tools you need )
        [18] => Array ( [0] => achieve results )
        [19] => Array ( [0] => criticone online intelligence )
        [20] => Array ( [0] => gain knowledge amp drive business results )
        [21] => Array ( [0] => 60 seconds View )
        [22] => Array ( [0] => plans Questions 1300 664 )
        [23] => Array ( [0] => 1 website )
        [24] => Array ( [0] => numerous microsites )
        [25] => Array ( [0] => Author images )
        [26] => Array ( [0] => author images )
        [27] => Array ( [0] => 1300 664 )
        [28] => Array ( [0] => Learn how )
        [29] => Array ( [0] => rough seas )
        [30] => Array ( [0] => tools empowering you )
        [31] => Array ( [0] => complex , take control )
        [32] => Array ( [0] => tools you need )
        [33] => Array ( [0] => achieve results )
        [34] => Array ( [0] => ..,Leverage criticone online intelligence )
        [35] => Array ( [0] => gain knowledge & ; drive business results )
        [36] => Array ( [0] => 60 seconds View )
        [37] => Array ( [0] => plans Questions 1300 664 )
        [38] => Array ( [0] => 550,Why 1 )
        [39] => Array ( [0] => numerous microsites )
        [40] => Array ( [0] => Author images ) )
```

criticone

Comment: Which array value are you after? A simple foreach loop or two should help you here...

Comment: Can you post the array with decent formatting, so we can see what you're looking for?

Comment: Why are all your array elements arrays with just one element? Why not just put those strings directly in the main array, instead of sub-arrays?

Comment: Also, the first element looks suspicious. Why is the index `[]` instead of `[0]`? I suspect the loop that creates this array didn't initialize the index before using `$i++` to increment it. You probably should find the code that creates the array and rewrite it to do sensible things.

Answer (score 0):

You could either access it "directly":

```
echo $demo[2][0]; // "online exposure"
```

Or if you need to go through all or several of the elements use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($demo as $key => $subarr)
{
    if ($key > 5)
    {
        echo $subarr[0];
    }
}
```

Which prints all the values from array index 6 upwards.

*Notice:* These are just (pretty stupid) examples to show how to deal with a multidimensional array. Also there are many more ways to deal with them, these are just (to me) the two most natural ones. Hope it helps.